# Django get_or_create suppress output to shell

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

This is just a curiosity, as my script is working and I just want to tidy it up. I'm [executing the django `get_or_create` function](https://django-chinese-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/models/querysets.html#get-or-create) inside a for loop where I check a rather long list for matching objects in my DB. The function returns a tuple: the object retrieved or created, and  a boolean. As I'm not working with the returned object, I'm just wondering if there is a way to suppress the output of this function to the shell.

**i.e. when I iterate over my list and run `get_or_create` I don't want thousands of useless `(<SomeModel: SomeModel object>, False/True)` cluttering my shell buffer. I'd rather see my print statements as I've structured them in my script. Anyway to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

You can just save the output of the function to variables so that it isn't printed:

```
obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

And then discard those variables.